# this code gives me TypeError: view must be a callable or list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: django

```
from django.conf import urls

from django.conf.urls import include, url

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from django.contrib import admin

from cs243.view import login,index2,studentprofile,photo,postgrad,undergrad,srsec,sec,languages,projects

from credentials.views import internships,contact,language


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^login/$', login),

    url(r'^index2/$', index2),

    url(r'^studentprofile/$', studentprofile),

    url(r'^photo/$', photo),

    url(r'^postgrad/$', postgrad),

    url(r'^undergrad/$', undergrad),

    url(r'^srsec/$', srsec),

    url(r'^sec/$', sec),

    url(r'^internships/$', internships),

    url(r'^languages/$', languages),

    url(r'^contact/$', contact),

    url(r'^projects/$', projects),

    url(r'^language/(?P<language>[a-z\-]+)/$', language),

    url(r'^auth/$'[enter image description here][1], 'cs243.view.auth_view'),

    url(r'^invalid/$', 'cs243.view.invalid_login'),

    url(r'^loggedin/$', 'cs243.view.loggedin'),

    url(r'^register/$', 'cs243.view.register_user'),

    url(r'^register_success/$', 'cs243.view.register_success'),
  ]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUGV6.png)

Comment: your views is funcion based?

Comment: Seems it's because the view for `r'^auth/$` is defined as string?

Comment: This is *not* a question. You should explain *what* you aim to do, what you tried, and what is not working. See [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

just do one thing instead of importing views functions like you have done, do,

```
     from . import view
```

then in line no. 38

```
     url(r'^auth/$','view.auth_view'),
```